# Меню - показывать один пункт скрывая другой

Tags: jquery, menu

Классическое меню с подпунктами:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="#">click</a>
      <ul class="pod">
        <li><a href="">dodo</a></li>
        <li><a href="">dodo1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
    <li class="first"><a href="#">click</a>
      <ul class="pod">
        <li><a href="">dodo</a></li>
        <li><a href="">dodo1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#">click</a></li>
</ul>
```

Необходимо, при клике на ссылку внутри li, разворачивать вложенное подменю и сворачивать другие, если они открыты.

Сейчас, скрипт разворачивает подменю, но не сворачивает другие открытые:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li a').click(function(event) {
        $(event.target).parent('.first').children('.pod').slideToggle(100);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

CSS скрывающий подменю изначально:

```
ul li ul {display: none;}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/by60keug/

Прошу подсказки, как доработать функционал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul li a').click(function(event) {

    if ($(event.target).parents(".pod").length) {
      // клик по ссылке на меню
      return false;
    }

    var $thisPod = $(event.target).parent('.first').children('.pod');
    $('.first .pod').not($thisPod).hide();
    $thisPod.slideToggle(100);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Классно, оперативно, спасибо! Только hide заменил на slideUp(300), что бы элементы исчезали тоже плавно

Comment: Пока печатал комментарии и тестировал, ответ изменился и стал лучше) Спасибо еще раз. Сейчас все как нужно, только можно ли сделать, что бы при клике по ссылке в выпадающем меню оно не схлопывало пункты?

Comment: Не хочу показаться чрезмерно дотошным, но теперь ссылка в подменю не реагирует и на переход по href="" )..

Comment: @Amsterdam замените `return false;` на `return;`

Comment: И в третий раз - спасибо!

Comment: @Amsterdam На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: хотелось бы к вам обратиться, по одному вопросу. Требуется доработка небольшого скрипта. Если у вас найдется время и будет интерес, напишите, пожалуйста, на почту ratedapa @ yandex ru. Доработка оплачиваемая.